# Newcommand with accents

Tags: macros, accents

I would like to create a command to automatically generate accented letters like è or é.

I tried:

```
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\´#1}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\`#1}

\ar{e}
\al{e}
```

but the result was "Undefined sequence".

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! You don't need to add *thanks* to your posts. Upvote answers you like, which is the TeX.SE way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I think you may have a non-ascii character, `´`, in the first `\newcommand`; hence, TeX doesn't recognize the control sequence `\´` and generates an error message. Just use an ordinary apostrophe instead: `\'`.

The following modified form of your code should do the job for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\'{#1}}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\`{#1}}
\begin{document}
\ar{e}
\al{e}
\end{document}​
```

[image]